# Jmeter: normalize-space to remove white spaces

Tags: jmeter

How do I remove extra spaces in tile ? Using below throws an error as unknown
  node:normalize-space. this is the one I tried.
   //td[@class="title"]/text()/normalize-space(.)

```
     <html>
     <head>
     <body>
     <table class="secondhead" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td class="title">
     My status Report (ABCDEFGH12160916)
     <span style="font-size:14pt;color:#00FF00"> * Live, Billable, CRM *                                                                          
     </span>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </body>
     </head>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [XPath functions reference](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp)

> fn:normalize-space(string)
>
> fn:normalize-space()
>
> Removes leading and trailing spaces from the specified string, and replaces all internal sequences of white space with one and returns the result. If there is no string argument it does the same on the current node
>
> Example: `normalize-space(' The   XML ')`
>
> Result: `'The XML'`

So you should be using the following expression instead:

```
normalize-space(//td[@class="title"]/text())
```

Check out [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide to learn more about dealing with XPath and JSON Path in JMeter

Comment: dimitri - How do I make titile display as: MystatusReport(ABCDEFGH12160916)   I do not want any spaces in title

Comment: translate(normalize-space(//td[@class="dealertitle"]/text()),' ','' ) - -this one resolved.. Thanks Dimitri